# How to use NSTimer to fire off multiple times?

Tags: swift, nstimer

I have a RNG and want it to go off every three seconds. So far I have

```
var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self , selector: randomnumbers, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func randomnumbers() {
    var rockNamesArray:[String] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]

    var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
}
```

But I have a bunch of error messages and I'm not sure how to organize it.

**EDIT**

The error message in this code is telling me that it has an unresolved identifier "self" and all the other error s are just ones occuring because I have changed this code, like unresolved identifier rockNamesArray and rockpos which happen 4 times in three different lines of code.

**EDIT2**

As stated in the comment the above code is placed outside of a class which explains that `self` is not working. But how to address the timer routine in this case?

Comment: So which error messages?

Comment: In general, we don't care enough to copy/paste your code into a boilerplate template to see what errors you're getting. Please give them to us in the question. (Note that I said _in the question_; **do not** post them in the comments)

Comment: You can not refer to `self` in the first phase of Two-Phase Initialization when assigning an initial value to your stored property `timer`.Please check the chapter `Initialization` of `The Swift Programming Language` for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

> it has an unresolved identifier "self"

It sounds like the code you've provided is not part of an instance method. `self` is a keyword that refers to the object whose code is executing. If you don't have an object, there's no `self`, hence the error. To solve the problem, you could pass a pointer to some other object that has a `randomnumbers` selector in place of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var timer = NSTimer(timeInterval:3, target:self, selector:Selector("randomnumbers:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func randomnumbers(timer:NSTimer) {
    var rockNamesArray:[String] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]

    var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))
}
```

since the timer routine expects a timer object.

**Edit** You need to place it inside a (dummy) class like this:

```
class MyTimer {
  var timer: NSTimer
  init() {
    timer = NSTimer(timeInterval:3, target:self , selector:Selector("randomnumbers:"), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
  }

  func randomnumbers(timer:NSTimer) {
    // ...
  }
}

let myTimer = MyTimer()
```

Comment: it says that use of unresolved identifier self. I have it on the outside of viewcontroller, but if I put it in the viewcontroller class the RNG wont work.

Comment: Just to instantiate your timer routine so it can run.

Answer (score 0):

Write `selector: "randomnumbers"` instead of `selector: randomnumbers`. You can instantiate the timer and start it at the same time using `timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead of `timer = NSTimer(timeInterval...`. Call this in your controller, e.g. in viewDidLoad

Please also note that your randomnumbers() does not do anything. You assign value to rockpos, but do not do anything with it. So you won't be able to see if the timer is working...

Comment: This likely won't work since the timer routine expects a timer object as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can not refer to `self` as a value when assigning an initial value to every stored property before the completion of the first phase of initialization in Swift.

As `The Swift Programming Language` says:

> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the new instance is considered ready for use.
>
> An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete.